OPKG Fails GPG Signature Verification Despite Manual GPG Validation: Bad signature
I am setting up an OPKG feed on an embedded system and am encountering issues with GPG signature verification. Here's the setup and the problem:
Setup Details:
Generated a GPG key using:
gpg --quick-generate-key "Name  <mail id>" rsa4096 sign

Signed Packages.gz using:
gpg --detach-sign --armor Packages.gz
mv Packages.gz.asc Packages.asc

Added the public key to /etc/opkg/gpg/pubring.gpg:
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/opkg/gpg/pubring.gpg --import <public_key_file>

Verified the signature manually:
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/opkg/gpg/pubring.gpg --verify Packages.asc Packages.gz

The output confirms a valid signature:
gpg: Good signature from "GivEnergy <givenergyhems@givenergy.co.uk>" [ultimate]

Configured opkg.conf:
option check_signature 1
src/gz local-feed http://<server _ip of ipk files>:8000/armv8a
option signature_type gpg-asc

Problem:
When I run opkg update, OPKG fails to verify the GPG signature:
root@imx93-var-som:/etc/opkg# opkg update
Downloading http://192.168.1.19:8000/armv8a/Packages.gz.
Downloading http://192.168.1.19:8000/armv8a/Packages.asc.
 * opkg_verify_gpg_signature: Signature status returned error: Bad signature
 * pkg_src_verify: Signature verification failed for local-feed.
root@imx93-var-som:/etc/opkg#

Steps Tried:

Verified the signature manually using GPG outside of OPKG — works
fine.
Set the key to "ultimate trust" via gpg --edit-key.
Cleared /var/lib/opkg/lists/ and retried opkg update.
Verified file permissions (e.g., chmod 644
/etc/opkg/gpg/pubring.gpg).
Exported trust explicitly using gpg --export-ownertrust and imported
it.
Tested GPGME installation (opkg info gpgme) — it is installed.

